# Connecting a SignalR hub in MVC project with authentication, from a console app using SignalR client

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, signalr

I have a MVC project containing a SignalR hub, to which only authenticated users can connect. The Hub class in my MVC project looks like below:

```
[Authorize]
public class DataHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to connect to this hub in a local Console App project. I have managed to login to the MVC using the following code successfully:

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
var respTxt1 = client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:44372/").Result;
// Finding __RequestVerificationToken in login view page.
respTxt1 = respTxt1.Substring(respTxt1.IndexOf("\"__RequestVerificationToken\""));
respTxt1 = respTxt1.Substring(respTxt1.IndexOf("value=\""));
respTxt1 = respTxt1.Substring(respTxt1.IndexOf("\"") + 1);
var __RequestVerificationToken = respTxt1.Substring(0, respTxt1.IndexOf("\""));

var values = new Dictionary<string, string>{
            { "Username", "*My Registered Username*" },
            { "Password", "*Password*" },
            { "__RequestVerificationToken", __RequestVerificationToken }
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var resp2 = client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44372/Account/Login?", content).Result;
```

I have checked this part of code and it works well. My question is how can I use this logged in client to establish a connection to my SignalR hub. I have tried the following code and it doesn't work:

```
var signalrConnection = new HubConnection("https://localhost:44339/");
signalrConnection.CookieContainer = cookies; // cookies is initiated in the previous codeblock
IHubProxy myHub = signalrConnection.CreateHubProxy("DataHub");
signalrConnection.Start().Wait();
```

The raised exception says
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:44339

Comment: Did you configured CORS?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with CORS. Some data in the MVC app needs to be updated continuously and I want to update them using a console app connecting to the MVC app through signalr.